# What performance loss is expected when (# of reducers) for a job exceeds the capacity of the cluster?

Tags: hadoop

I configure (# of mappers/reducers) per node in hadoop in its configuration files.

I submit any MR tasks specifying (# of mappers/reducers) to be used.

What performance loss is expected when (# of reducers) for a job exceeds the capacity of the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. #### Number of Mappers may not be specified!

   Number of mappers set to run are completely dependent on

   1. File Size
   2. Block Size

---

2. There is no straightforward way to estimate the loss in performance for your case. It depends on the type of reduction and depends a lot on the data.

   For example: Suppose your data is such that one of the reduction runs too long then the other reducers would complete and start the second reduction job. Hence maybe completing all the reductions by the time the one big reduction happens.